# Airflow dag's task sleeps and the scheduler stops executing other dags

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have 2 dags. One of them has a python task which polls an API for status of the task every 5 seconds and sleeps. On successful status it moves ahead. I was just fiddling around with it and increased sleep time to 50 seconds and noticed that the scheduler also sleeps and does not execute other dags. How to sleep and not affect execution of other dags.